# How to reference a file in the workspace, in a subprocess Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-imaging-library

Currently, I have a program that is able to download an image from the web, which saves it in the same directory the python project is saved in.

I am using

```
r=subprocess.Popen(["rundll32.exe","shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen","C:\\pic.jpg"])
time.sleep(3)
r.kill()
```

to view an image and then close it after a time (which is essential), however when i change the path from "`C:\\pic.jpg`" to "`C:\Users\...\assignment1\pic.jpg`" I get a unicode error in the path, and if i change the start of the path to "`C:\\`" (with two slashes, cant format :( ), then i get no error but the file simply just doesn't open.

Does the path always have to be referenced from C:\ or is there some sort of buzzword that goes straight to the default directory?

```
urlretrieve("%s?%s" % (url,parameters),"pic.jpg")
```

this is the method used to save the file, which saves in the default directory

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the **full text** of any errors you are getting.

Comment: Try giving the filename as just `'pic.jpg'`, without trying to specify the actual path with `'C:\\ etc.'`. It looks like the image should be saved in Python's current working directory, and it should be reachable just using the filename.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to the `\U` in your string, which Python tries to interpret as a `\Uxxxxxxxx` escape sequence (where the `x`s are hex digits for a 32-bit Unicode ordinal). The problem you're getting after doubling the first backslash probably has to do with some other escape sequence later in the path (`\a` becomes the ASCII "BEL" character, for instance).

You need to either escape *all* the backslashes, or tell Python not to look for escape sequences by making the path a "raw" string literal: `r"C:\Users\...\assignment1\pic.jpg"`